# Getting Nan output when using console.log to check

Tags: javascript, html, nan

I am not sure why I am getting NaN error on the console. The span id=" score" with 0 as a default value, the points don't get updated despite converting it to number already. Basically, it is a number game whereby there are 3 boxes, with different id. Onclick, it checks for the input selected by the user and check if the number is the same and gains 3 points if tallies and minus 2 point if it is wrong.

sample :
[image: sample]

```
function checkAnswer(){
    
    var scoredPoints = document.getElementById("score");
    var updatedScore = Number(scoredPoints.value); 
    var finalScore;
    var answer = document.getElementById("listofOptions");
    var check = Number(answer.value);
    
    var numberOne = document.getElementById("one");
    var numberTwo = document.getElementById("two");
    var numberThree = document.getElementById("three");
    var check1 = Number(numberOne.value);
    var check2 = Number(numberTwo.value);
    var check3 = Number(numberThree.value);
    
    if(check == check1 || check == check2 || check == check3)
    {   
        finalScore = updatedScore + 3;
        scoredPoints.innerHTML=finalScore;
        console.log(finalScore);
    }
    else{       
        finalScore = updatedScore - 2;
        scoredPoints.innerHTML=finalScore;
        console.log(finalScore);
    }
    scoredPoints.value = finalScore;
    
}
```

Comment: Can we see the HTML?

Comment: Code looks fine, problem must be with your HTML.
Also try reducing variable declarations.

Comment: Are you getting any value on the very second line of your function, which is "updatedScore"?

Comment: <span style="color:red" id="score"><font size="5"><b>0</b></font></span>

this part is my score . i am getting nan for updatedScore , just did console.log .

Comment: <td width="33%" bgcolor="#c3ddf0"><form> <!--action="" method="post" -->
           <select id ="listofOptions">            
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
           </select>

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you put

```
<span style="color:red" id="score"><font size="8"><b>0</b></font></span>
```

and the following code will give you NaN because span element doesn't have a value attribute

```
var scoredPoints = document.getElementById("score");
var updatedScore = Number(scoredPoints.value);
```

In order to get the value 0, which is text within span, the following is required.

```
var updatedScore = Number(scoredPoints.textContent);
```

Note: value had been replaced with textContent.

You may have to do the same for the following code by replacing .value with .textContent if you still have NaN. I can't tell from lack of HTML if that is the case.

```
var check1 = Number(numberOne.value);
var check2 = Number(numberTwo.value);
var check3 = Number(numberThree.value);
```

Comment: appreciated! i have solved it though !! thanks again!